# Is there a simple closed form solution for the joint density distribution of an exponential distribution with a rate given by a Gamma distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is drawn from a Gamma distribution with shape and scale parameters $(k,\theta)$.  I'd like to calculate an exact PDF for values, $v_i$, drawn from the exponential distribution if, for each sampling event, we randomly sample a value of $\lambda$ from the aforementioned Gamma distribution.  Is there a simple closed-form solution for the PDF of the $v_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(t,s)= f(t\mid s)\cdot f(s) = \frac1{\theta^k\Gamma(k)} s e^{-st}\cdot s^{k-1}\cdot e^{-s/\theta}
$$
$$
= \frac1{\theta^k\Gamma(k)} s^{k}\cdot e^{-st-s/\theta}
$$
for $s>0$, $t>0$. Here $s=\lambda$.

Comment: Yikes, good point.  I changed the Gaussian to a Gamma distribution with shape and scale parameters $(k,\theta)$.

Comment: What about calculating a marginal distribution of the $v_i$?  Can this be done?

Comment: That's fair enough, and thanks for humoring me with your answer. :)

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88086/calculating-a-marginal-distribution-for-the-joint-density-distribution-of-an-exp